# Pretty print / clean up BIND 9 zone file

Tags: formatting, text-formatting, bind

I inherited some BIND 9 zone files that are terrible mess, bad indentation, directive order is different than typical, etc. Is there some utility that can clean them up, in the sense of reformatting them to readable shape?

Comment: Maybe try a zone transfer (i.e. dig axfr) on the DNS server and store that output as a text file.  Then use that output as the new zone file.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively easy, although probably not completely satisfying, solution is to download the zone files from the nameserver itself. This will give you a sorted and easily parsable list:

```
mtak@svc1:~$ dig -t AXFR int.mtak.nl @127.0.0.1

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u15-Debian <<>> -t AXFR int.mtak.nl @127.0.0.1
;; global options: +cmd
int.mtak.nl.        86400   IN  SOA svc1.int.mtak.nl. root.int.mtak.nl. 2016060407 600 15 604800 30
int.mtak.nl.        86400   IN  NS  svc1.int.mtak.nl.
int.mtak.nl.        86400   IN  NS  svc2.int.mtak.nl.
int.mtak.nl.        86400   IN  A   10.100.0.82
ans1.int.mtak.nl.   86400   IN  A   10.100.0.73
ap3.int.mtak.nl.    86400   IN  A   10.100.0.16
atlas.int.mtak.nl.  86400   IN  A   10.100.3.18
bck1.int.mtak.nl.   86400   IN  A   10.100.0.90
bck2.int.mtak.nl.   86400   IN  A   10.100.0.91
btsync.int.mtak.nl. 86400   IN  A   10.100.0.76
cacti.int.mtak.nl.  86400   IN  A   10.100.0.75
clients-100.int.mtak.nl. 86400  IN  A   10.100.4.100
clients-101.int.mtak.nl. 86400  IN  A   10.100.4.101
clients-102.int.mtak.nl. 86400  IN  A   10.100.4.102
clients-103.int.mtak.nl. 86400  IN  A   10.100.4.103
[...]
```